# Azure devtest labs VM IP address

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, azure-networking

The problem  was the ability to utilize an IP address that was already assigned to an interface.

**For example**

I create an X3 VM with the IP of `10.0.16.9`.  It creates a network interface on that image of `10.0.16.9`.  X3 is IP reliant, so any clone that you make of that VM needs to have the same internal IP address to function properly.

If I create VMs off of the clone in a different resource group it changes the subnet to the subnet assigned to that resource group, for example `10.0.17.0`.

I can try to make a custom network interface to deploy with that VM with the same IP address, but run into an issue where it knows that IP is assigned elsewhere, and cannot be used again.

Comment: Can you try to reformat and make it clearer what the actual question is?

Comment: Yes. I've rearranged my question. The question was can I keep internal private IP after deploy from an Azure image?

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt, I want to make clear that the IP address is assigned by Azure and the default assignment way is Dynamic. The Private IP address is assigned in the NIC.

NIC is also a type of resources in Azure. When you create a new Azure VM, the NIC will also be created and attached to the VM. The NIC is not linked to your image. **So, the pravite IP address is not linked to your image.** **It means that you cannot keep the private IP via just deploying VM from image**.

The image cannot contains the information about the outside resouces. It just contains the Customer OS. Actually, the image will be used to a Disk, which is also a type of resources in Auzre.

However, you can still change the pravite IP address via Azure Portal:

Go to Azure portal > find the resource group which contains your Devtest VM > Select the NIC of that VM > IP configuration > Select the configuration > Enable Static Assignment for IP address > change the IP addresss > Save

Addtional, within one VNet you cannot use the same pravite IP for multiple resouces.